# Срезы по датам в мультииндексах

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, multi-index

Есть набор данных:

```
    dates = ['2018-11-30 23:40:15', '2018-11-30 23:41:05',
             '2018-11-30 23:41:15', '2018-12-01 00:08:57',
             '2018-12-01 00:09:12', '2018-12-01 00:27:56',
             '2018-12-01 00:28:56', '2018-12-01 00:39:37', 
             '2018-12-01 00:44:18', '2018-12-01 00:45:18']
    
    dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)
    
    ind = [['id_1','id_1','id_1','id_1','id_1',
                     'id_2', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_3', 'id_3'], dates]
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), index=ind, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Знаю, что можно в индексе второго уровня указывать конкретную дату и получать все данные, соответствующие ей. Так:

```
df.loc['id_1', '2018-11-30']
```

Можно ли взять срез по дате и времени (например, выбрать все данные, с индексом id_1 до заданного времени включительно)?

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
df.loc['id_1', :'2018-12-01 00:08:57']
```

или так, если до конкретного числа нужны данные:

```
df.loc['id_1', :'2018-12-01']
```

В итоге, выводятся сами индексы, а нужно DataFrame с данными до конкретного времени включительно, указанного в индексе.

Можно ли вообще делать таким образом срезы? Если да, то как?

Наглядный пример того, что имеется в виду:

```
df.loc['id_1', :'2018-12-01 00:08:57']
```

Ожидаю увидеть:

[image]

Comment: Поняла, это решается так:  df.loc['id_1'].loc[:'2018-12-01 00:08:57'], можно ли при помощи одного метода loc это сделать как-то?

Comment: +1 за отлично оформленный вопрос с __воспроизводимым__ примером данных)

Comment: Большое спасибо! очень не хочу обременять кого-либо тратить лишнюю энергию на расшифровку вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [pd.IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) - он специально создан для облегчения работы со срезами мульти-индексов:

```
In [32]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [33]: res = df.loc[idx['id_1', :'2018-12-01 00:08:57'], :]

In [34]: res
Out[34]:
                              col1      col2      col3
id_1 2018-11-30 23:40:15 -0.748932 -1.502318  0.593789
     2018-11-30 23:41:05  1.451214 -0.943655  0.566013
     2018-11-30 23:41:15  1.354764  0.044922  0.149455
     2018-12-01 00:08:57 -0.946963  0.439159  1.503776
```

Comment: очень полезный метод, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте через срезы:

```
df.loc[(slice("id_1"), slice(None, '2018-12-01 00:08:57')), :]
```

Comment: спасибо, вот так вроде попроще:  df.loc['id_1'].loc[:'2018-12-01 00:08:57']

Comment: @onetwoonexu вы спросили про метод с одним loc - я вам написал. к тому же, есть подозрение, что через срезы будет чуть эффективнее, но это не точно.

Comment: поняла Вас, спасибо)